# Critical battery action gracefully shutdowns instead of hibernating

Tags: power-management, shutdown, hibernate

Running Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Enabled hibernation and manually tested pm-hibernate successfully.
I updated the values in the gnome power manager i.e.

- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy false
- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 5
- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 4
- org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action
  'hibernate'

I get the warning at 5%, but when I hit 4% I get another warning that the computer will shutdown after which it *gracefully* shuts down instead of hibernating! I tried with the values 6%/5% as well, but no luck. I even tried to hibernate when I got that shutdown warning and it worked... but when I resumed with A/C, it gracefully shutdown right away since that command must have been queued just before I hibernated.

So I spent the last hour looking for a solution, but no one seems to have the exact same problem. People seem to complain about a sudden shutdown (as if there was no power left at all), not a graceful one. I haven't tried the solution suggesting the use of laptop-mode-tools, since I want to install more stuff on my laptop than necessary (and some people complained of sluggish behaviour following that route).

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: The values are too low. Change the value for action to atleast 10%.

Comment: Hibernate only takes a few second, so I don't understand why I would need to start taking a critical action when I have 20+ minutes of battery... but I'm willing to give it a try! I'll report back once I hit 10%...

Comment: I too don't understand but I have already tried what you are trying now, and the least possible value I found out was to be 10%. But if you use heavy programs such as avconv, then your laptop will hard shutdown even at 10%.

Comment: No luck :(  I set it to warning at 11% and action at 10%. I still get the graceful shutdown. Any logs I can look at to try to understand what's happening?

Comment: Did you add the shutdown action  as .pkla?

Comment: I don't remember doing that... so I'd say no. Let me google it... but you mean adding hibernate or shutdown?

Comment: Here - this is what you need to do - http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: GREAT! That did it -- thanks. And it works at 4% as I initially set it up. Want to submit the answer so I can close this one?

Comment: Wait a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling the hibernate seems to solve the issue. The solution can be found here at [ubuntuhandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/).

Comment: :) Welcome. Glad! it helped.